# Keyboard shortcut to switch files in one Emacs instance?

Tags: files, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I've multiple files opened in an Emacs client. Right now, to toggle between files, I've to click on the file name at the bar below in the editor. Any keyboard shortcuts for switching between files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will change between last two files.

To go to any buffer whose name starts with `xy` use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

To list the buffers: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to get rid of the split window.

Comment: Anthon, something like Alt+Tab?

Comment: Alt+Tab is handle by the window manager on my system to switch between program windows. The `Ctrl` is configurable, but I guess you (still) would have the default setup.

Comment: @FireAndIce http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers

Comment: Anthon, how do I navigate through the buffer? I'm unable to do it through keyboard. How do I bring the cursor in the buffer list?

Comment: After Ctrl+x Ctrl+b, the buffer list pops up but the cursor still remains in the first window.

Comment: I use the bufferlist only when I lose track, search for a name. And close it with the `Ctrl+x 1`. You can switch between split windows with ``Ctrl+x o`

Comment: Your welcome. Try to give back to the community if you can at some point, when **you** have useful answers.

Comment: I'll surely do that.. :)